# How to detect presence of a file on web server

Tags: objective-c, ios

What would be the correct way in iOS of detecting the presence of a file (HTML) on a web server. Using the following to detect the presence of myfile.html always returns true.

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://somewebsite.com/myfile.html"];
NSURLRequest *requestObject = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

NSURLConnection *theConnection=[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:requestObject delegate:self];

if (theConnection) {

    NSLog(@"File exists");

} else {

    NSLog(@"File does NOT exist");
}
```

I believe it is returning that the connection to HTTP server is successful, and not checking if the file myfile.html actually exists.

Comment: Using the HEAD HTTP method instead of GET by calling `[requestObject setHTTPMethod:@"HEAD"];` on a `NSMutableURLRequest` should be sufficient if you are not interested in the file contents.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you'll need to use the connection:didReceiveResponse delegate method to check the http response code. something like the following will check to make sure you got a 200 response back, depending on your server i'd expect the status code to be 404 if the file doesn't exist.

```
- (void) connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {
    //make sure we have a 2xx reponse code
    NSHTTPURLResponse *httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse *)response;

    if ([httpResponse statusCode]/100 == 2){
        NSLog(@"file exists");
    } else {
        NSLog(@"file does not exist");
    }
}
```

Comment: A follow-up question: the above code works, but the delegate method completes asynchronously. how to reliably check in the main program (not in the delegate) if the file exists?

Comment: you'd need to use the sendSynchronousRequest:returningResponse:error:
 NSURLConnection method to send a synchronous request. if you go that route you can probably just use the returningResponse variable to check the return code, i don't believe the delegate method gets called with a sync request